# c++ remove pixels from dialog round corners

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog

I want to remove some pixels that are visible in dialog window which has round corners and i cant find any solution in c++

Here is the code i use and as far as i searched i think i need to use UpdateLayeredWindow function instead of SetLayeredWindowAttributes in the WS_EX_LAYERED window but i cant find the way to do it.

Does anyone knows how to remove this pixels from the round corners of my dialog ?

Code:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hh,UINT mm,WPARAM ww,LPARAM)
    {
    HWND hX = GetDlgItem(hh,123);

    switch(mm)
        {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            {
            // No Dialog Title Bar 
            SetWindowLong(hh, GWL_STYLE, 0); // With no border around the window 
            // Transparent Dialog In Selected Color
            LONG ExtendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hh, GWL_EXSTYLE);
            SetWindowLong(hh, GWL_EXSTYLE, ExtendedStyle | WS_EX_LAYERED);
            SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hh, RGB(255, 128, 255), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);
            //UpdateLayeredWindow(hh, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, RGB(255, 128, 255), 0, ULW_COLORKEY);

            // Load the swf from our resources, extract first to temp path
            TCHAR dx[1000] = {0};
            GetTempPath(1000,dx);
            TCHAR df[1000] = {0};
            GetTempFileName(dx,L"swf",0,df);
            DeleteFile(df);
            wcscat_s(df,1000,L".swf");
            DeleteFile(df);
            ExtractDefaultFile(df,L"flash",0,0,L"data");

            SendMessage(hX,AX_INPLACE,1,0);
            SendMessage(hh,WM_SIZE,0,0);

            // Set the object
            IShockwaveFlash* p = 0;
            CLSID iidx = __uuidof(IShockwaveFlash);
            HRESULT hr = (HRESULT)SendMessage(hX,AX_QUERYINTERFACE,(WPARAM)&iidx,(LPARAM)&p);
            if (p)
                {
                _bstr_t x(df);
                hr = p->put_WMode(L"transparent");
                hr = p->put_BackgroundColor(RGB(255,128,255));
                hr = p->put_Movie(x);

                // Notification
                AX* iax = (AX*)SendMessage(hX,AX_GETAXINTERFACE,0,0);
                if (iax)
                    {
                    axCookie = AXConnectObject(iax->OleObject,__uuidof(_IShockwaveFlashEvents),(IUnknown*)&fn,&cpc,&cp);
                    }


                p->Release();
                }

            break;
            }
        case WM_SIZE:
            {
            RECT rc;
            GetClientRect(hh,&rc);
            SetWindowPos(hX,0,0,0,rc.right,rc.bottom,SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
            return 0;
            }

        case WM_CLOSE:
            {
            EndDialog(hh,0);
            return 0;
            }
        }
    return 0;
    }

int __stdcall WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE,LPSTR,int)
    {
    OleInitialize(0);
    AXRegister();

    DialogBox(hInstance,L"DIALOG_MAIN",0,WinProc);
    return 0;
    }
```

I am using a color of RGB(255, 128, 255) which is not used inside the flash as color otherwise it erases also the color from inside the flash player.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look into "Masking" or "Clipping Region" for WinAPI. You'll want to use: `CreateRoundRectRgn`.

Comment: If you are seeing extra pixels on the edges of the window, it means those pixels do not match your specified transparency color. For instance, if the edges are blurred or anti-aliased, or are blended with another color or a shadow.

Comment: Yes Remy, you are correct too. It seems that activex with transparency and removing the WS_EX_LAYERED color mapping is having some issues especially at round corners, i found 2 ways one with CreateRoundRectRgn as Brandon and  xMRi suggested and another is to avoid using opacity or alpha blends inside the activex that is loaded. Not using shadows, alpha blends and other effects that are having issues with color mapping is a good solution and also without them some pixels at round edges may occur, Best method is using both as it seems till now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a region wit a win32 function. i.e. CreateEllipticRegion, CreateRectRgn...
2. Than you have to use SetWindowRgn.

Here is a [link](http://comrade.ownz.com/docs/shapewnd.html) to a pure Win32 discussion. And here a [link](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/frameworks/advancedui/article.php/c6069/Change-the-Shape-of-the-Window.htm) to a MFC sample. Should be easy to transfer it to WinAPI pure

Comment: Thanks Brandon and xMRi for the link, yes it worked by setting a region with round corners at the flash hwnd, it removed the bad pixels but the result is a bit of pixeled corners but at least it did the job :) thanks